# Telerik RadGrid returning "wrong" data item in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, linq, telerik, radgrid

So I have a series of RadGrids that are databound via LINQ queries.  Associated with each is a combobox that allows you to filter the results for a desired entity.  All that works fine...  But when I click on the edit button after filtering, it returns the wrong row.  It looks like when I click "edit" it fires the "needsdata" event which is fetching the unfiltered dataset, and as a result I get the wrong row.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Paul

Comment: You need to move all your filtering into the NeedDataSource method.  That way you don't have to worry about how/when this is called, it always returns your filtered data for the controls to bind to.

Comment: @Seano666 oyyoyyoyyyyy :( I was afraid that was the case.  Ugh.  So, my thought was to store a session variable representing the filter value.  Then in the NeedDataSource, if the variable is not null it will use it in the query otherwise return the full dataset.  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Seano666 ... BTW, thanks!  Looks like you've become my patron saint of RadGrids ;)

Comment: Ok @Seano666 just tried out doing that in one of the zillions of grids on my page and seems to work fine... but thanks for the depressing reality check ;)

Comment: Glad to help man, your session value idea sounds good to me.  Seems weird at first, but it is actually helpful to have all the filtering logic in one place, that way you don't have to worry about when to call DataBind, or anything like that, the grid always has the data it needs and you can do a lot more dynamic stuff.